# How to add a launcher that opens all files with a specific extension in XFce?

Tags: xfce, launcher

If I type `geany ~/scripts/*.sh` in a terminal, it opens up Geany with all of those shell files ready to edit. If I add this same line to a custom launcher, it opens a file called "*.sh" instead. How can I tell the launcher to act like the terminal? I tried checking "open in terminal", but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your command in a call to Bash, specifically `bash -c "geany ~/scripts/*.sh"`.